# Making an SKLabelNode Ignore Touches

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch

In Swift and SpriteKit, you can designate an object as "isUserInteractionEnabled=false". Confusingly, this does not mean that the object will ignore touches and let those touches pass through to nodes below it.

The way I built SpriteKit apps it is very common for me to create a node (like a SKShapeNode or an SKSpriteNode) and then slap a label on it.  What I want is for the label to ignore touches and let those touches pass through to the node behind it but I am failing to understand how this is done, if "isUserInteractionEnable" is not the ticket.

Any suggestions?  Here is a sample label that receives touches but should not:

```
class MenuButton: SKShapeNode {

    /*  The MenuBar will have as children nine buttons of two types.  Dialog Springers and SubMenu Droppers  */

    // MARK: - Class Variables

    var title = "Button"
    var menu = SKShapeNode()

    let buttonLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: devFont4)

    init(title: String)
    {
        super.init()

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.title = title
        self.name = "\(title) Menu Button"
        let btnLen = title.count * 10 + 16

        let menuSize = CGSize(width: btnLen, height: 32)
        menu = SKShapeNode(rectOf: menuSize)
        addChild(menu)

        menu.fillColor = .clear
        menu.strokeColor = .clear
        menu.lineWidth = 0

        menu.zPosition = 501

        // Add Label
        let letterHeight: CGFloat = 22
        buttonLabel.text = title
        buttonLabel.name = "\(title) Label"
        buttonLabel.fontSize = letterHeight
        buttonLabel.fontColor = .black
        buttonLabel.zPosition = 502
        buttonLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(-letterHeight/2) + 2)
        buttonLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        addChild(buttonLabel)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one first responder to receive the touches event. The `isUserInteractionEnabled` is used to decide which one is called first even Both are enabled. Play the following codes and you can have a feeling what's going on.

```
class Button: SKLabelNode{
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("button")
}
}

class MenuButton: SKShapeNode {

/*  The MenuBar will have as children nine buttons of two types.  Dialog Springers and SubMenu Droppers  */

// MARK: - Class Variables

var title = "Button"
var menu = SKShapeNode()

let buttonLabel = Button.init()

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("hit")
}

init(title: String)
{
    super.init()

    isUserInteractionEnabled = true




    self.title = title
    self.name = "\(title) Menu Button"
    let btnLen = title.count * 10 + 16

    let menuSize = CGSize(width: btnLen, height: 32)
    menu = SKShapeNode(rectOf: menuSize)
    addChild(menu)

    menu.fillColor = .green
    menu.strokeColor = .clear
    menu.lineWidth = 0

    menu.zPosition = 501
    menu.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    // Add Label
    let letterHeight: CGFloat = 122

    buttonLabel.text = title
    buttonLabel.name = "\(title) Label"
    buttonLabel.fontSize = letterHeight
    buttonLabel.fontColor = .black
    buttonLabel.zPosition = 502
    buttonLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(-letterHeight/2) + 2)
    buttonLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addChild(buttonLabel)

     self.path = UIBezierPath.init(rect:self.calculateAccumulatedFrame()).cgPath
    self.fillColor = UIColor.red

 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Swift and SpriteKit, you can designate an object as
>   "isUserInteractionEnabled=false". Confusingly, this does not mean that
>   the object will ignore touches and let those touches pass through to
>   nodes below it.

That is incorrect,  isUserInteractionEnabled=false means that the object will ignore touches and let touches pass through it.

You have a completely different problem.  In your code,  your main menu does not have a size, so it is passing through your label, inner menu node, and outer menu node, hitting your scene.

Comment: I need to reacquaint myself with the SKShapeNode.  I am a bit too much of a hack for my own good.